# Service or IntentService Which method is better for keep alive session with server in android

Tags: android, session, service, intentservice, keep-alive

I want to keep alive my connection with server by Socket. Which one is better for this case? Service or IntentService? Why?

Comment: Use `Service` for keep alive connection.

Comment: yes need to use service

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a Service, because it will stay alive until you stop it. IntentService in the other hand stops itself when it runs out of work.

Answer (score 1):

`IntentService` is special `Service` that finish itself on its task finished.

`Service` is a component that can run indefinitely though the component that starts it is destroyed.

So if you want to run something forever and also you want to communicate with other Activity then you should go with `Service`.

But consider the following also:

1. `Service` runs in the same thread as of Main Thread but runs in background so heavy operation in service may affect your application performance. `IntentService` runs in worker thread separate from Main Thread thread.
2. With `Service` its your responsibility to start and stop it else it will run indefinitely. `IntentService` stops itself on task complete.
3. Generally `IntentService` is used for long running task whereas `Service` for not too long tasks.
4. You can bind `Service` to activity if you need to communicate with Activity. `IntentService` can be used for tasks with no communication to Main Thread. If communication is required, can use Main Thread handler or broadcast intents. Another case of use is when callbacks are needed (Intent triggered tasks).
5. `IntentService` cannot run tasks in parallel. Hence all the consecutive intents will go into the message queue for the worker thread and will execute sequentially.

So if you are doing heavy operation in background and you need not to communicate with Main Thread then you go with `IntentService` or else result needs to be passed to Main Thread and background task is not too heavy then you can go with `Service`.